# Rolling correlation pandas

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a dataframe with time series.
I'd like to compute the rolling correlation (periods=20) between columns.

```
store_corr=[] #empty list to store the rolling correlation of each pairs
names=[] #empty list to store the column name
df=df.pct_change(periods=1).dropna(axis=0) #Prepate dataframe of time series

for i in range(0,len(df.columns)):
    for j in range(i,len(df.columns)):
        corr = df[df.columns[i]].rolling(20).corr(df[df.columns[j]])
        names.append('col '+str(i)+' -col '+str(j))
        store_corr.append(corr)

df_corr=pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(np.array(store_corr)),columns=names)
```

This solution is working and gives me the rolling correlation.This solution is with the help of Austin Mackillop (comments).

Is there another faster way? (I.e. I want to avoid this double for loop.)

Comment: instead of adding the solution by editing your question, please leave the question as it was and add just add another answer (answering your own question is fine!). otherwise it's very confusing to see what is question and what is answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
corr=df.rolling(20).corr(df[df.columns[i]],df[df.columns[j]])
```

will produce an error because the second argument of `corr` expects a `Bool` but you passed a DataFrame which has an ambiguous truth value. You can view the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.corr.html#pandas.core.window.Rolling.corr).

Does applying the rolling method to the first DataFrame in the second line of code that you provided achieve what you are trying to do?

```
corr = df[df.columns[i]].rolling(20).corr(df[df.columns[j]])
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I have edited the code. The desired final output is a dataframe with each column being the rolling correlation of each pairs. I have added the line of code producing it as well.  However this whole thing takes a while. Is there a better way than doing this double for loop? Thanks!